# Change background of li element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `li` element like this:

```
    <li class="file file-success">
    </li>
```

I want to change its background using jQuery.

Note that I can't change the `li` element itself.

Comment: Are there any other <li>s with that class? If so you'll need CSS selectors too. It's pretty basic jQuery though, the docs will serve you well.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to change li text color or bullet color? The former can be achieved through this code:

```
$('li.file').css('background-color', 'yellow'});
```

If you want to change bullet image, here is the code:

```
$('li.file').css('list-style-image', 'url(yourimage.jpg)'});
```

Comment: i want to change its background with other image

Comment: You can change bullet image with list-style-image property. I've added necessary code to change it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$("li.file").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
```

or

```
$("li.file-success").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
```

depending on what CSS selector you want to use for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.file").css("background-image", "url(test.png)");
```

Comment: If you add a background image, you may also need to define it's height and width as well, in case the text contained in the li is too short